# How to turn my Live USB to Persistence Live USB?

Tags: usb, persistence

I don't have another computer to use rufus and create a persistent USB. For that reason I used my android to make my USB bootable. Yeah, I've created a ext4 partition. I just want to use that as a persistence drive. I have 2 partitions on my usb. 1 is fat 32 which is /dev/sda1. The second one is ext4 which is /dev/sda2. I want to use my /dev/sda2 as a persistence partition. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

### Turn Live USB into Persistence Live USB?

You **can not** use a FAT32 partition for persistence, for this you need ext2, ext3 or ext4. You can however add a persistence file named `writable` to a FAT32 partition, but it will be limited to 4GB. A second persistence file named `home-rw` can also be added for a total of 8GB.

**For a persistent partition:**

- Boot the USB using the `toram` option*.
- Unplug then replug the USB drive.
- Open GParted and create a second ext4 partition and label it either `writable` or `casper-rw`.
- Open the system partition and edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg adding a space and the word `persistent` to the end of the first menuentry right after ---.

If system partition is not editable, ie if it's ISO9660, or an ISO file, you may need to enable persistence each boot, (similar to using toram).

**If you decide to use persistence files:**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=casper-rw bs=1M count=512
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F casper-rw
```

- (Replace 512 with the "size in MB" you require, max 4000)
- For Ubuntu 20.04 and later replace `casper-rw` with `writable`
- For a `home-rw` partition replace `casper-rw` with `home-rw`

**Booting `toram`**

After turning on the computer, press `Shift`.

If it boots BIOS mode a language screen will come up, press `Esc`. Press `F6` then press `Esc` again. At the bottom of the screen type a space and `toram`.

If the computer boots to a GRUB menu, type the letter `e` next to the first menu item. Go down to the line that starts with `linux` and at the end of it after ---, type a space and `toram`. Press `F10` to boot.

Comment: If I create a persistence file, Will I have to repeat this thing everytime I boot?

Comment: I have created the home-rw and writable file. What should I do next?

Comment: Were you able to edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

Comment: there is no grub.cfg file. It doesn't exists

Comment: Where did you put the Ubuntu system files, The FAT32 partition or the ext4 partition? Is there a folder named **boot** with a folder named **grub** inside? Is there a folder named **cdrom**? look inside that.

Comment: The system files are in Fat32 partition. Yeah there is a boot folder. And yet there is also a folder called grub inside of it. But, There are no cdrom folder

Comment: I found it. I've opened the grub.cfg file. What to do next?

Comment: Add a space and the word `persistent` to the end linux line of the first menuentry right after ---, ie `linux /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash --- persistent`